# How to read a JSON Array in php without any key?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a JSON formed @Javascript and passed to PHP via AJAX , problem is that I cannot assign keys to each JSON Object inside the JSON Array .
The JSON Array looks something like this :
`[{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":101,"quantity":"3"},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":102,"quantity":"2"},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":103,"quantity":"4"},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":104,"quantity":"4"},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":105,"quantity":0},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":106,"quantity":"5"},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":107,"quantity":0},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":108,"quantity":0},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":109,"quantity":"4"}]`

,Now , in PHP ,how to iterate the data , I am a newbie to PHP , so please excuse me if I am asking a very silly question.

The link you provided has examples with key, mine is without key.

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29308898/3933332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = '[{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":101,"quantity":"3"},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":102,"quantity":"2"},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":103,"quantity":"4"},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":104,"quantity":"4"},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":105,"quantity":0},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":106,"quantity":"5"},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":107,"quantity":0},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":108,"quantity":0},{"jobId":"90","cname":"Subhasish","removal_id":109,"quantity":"4"}]';
$array = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($array as $item) {
echo $item['jobId']."-".$item['cname']."-".$item['removal_id']."-".$item['quantity']."\n";
}
```

**`Output
90-Subhasish-101-3
90-Subhasish-102-2
90-Subhasish-103-4
90-Subhasish-104-4
90-Subhasish-105-0
90-Subhasish-106-5
90-Subhasish-107-0
90-Subhasish-108-0
90-Subhasish-109-4`**

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7fb784239b9dd33d3c33e46c1082a858a4f0e7e9)

Answer (score 0):

Using json_decode($json_object).

```
$json = json_decode($json_object);
foreach($json as $j){
   print_r($j)
}
```